# node.js: data indexing in elasticsearch by using user defined id

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I need to index multiple jsons in elasticsearch and indexing id should be given by user not by automatically created by elasticserach.

Can any please tell me how to stop elasticsearch from creating automatic index id and how can I use my desired id for data indexing.

Below is the part of node.js code for indexing data:

```
elasticSearchClient.index('index_name', 'type', json)
                .on('data', function(data) {
                    console.log("************ "+data+" ****************")
                })
                .exec()
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

elasticSearchClient.bulk() is the solution for my problem.

Reference:
https://github.com/phillro/node-elasticsearch-client

Comment: Can you explain why? I don't get how your answer is related to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Just include the `id` field in your json document. It will be automatically extracted from the document and put in the url. In fact the [core.js](https://github.com/phillro/node-elasticsearch-client/blob/master/lib/elasticsearchclient/calls/core.js) script contains this logic:

```
if (document.id) {
    path += "/" + document.id
    method = 'PUT'
    delete document.id
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If we don't give indexing id then indexing id for document will be auto created by elasticsearch.

So I use below code and tell the indexing id for indexing doc.

```
var commands = []
 commands.push({ "index" : { "_index" :'opt', "_type" : "art", "_id":my_id} })
 commands.push(index_ingjson_doc)

 elasticSearchClient.bulk(commands, {})
                            .on('data', function(data) {
                            }).on('error', function(error){})
                            .exec();
```

In this way, I resolved my problem! Some other solutions may be possible but as of now I am using above code.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly, just put `"_id": whatever` into your JSON and ensure `index.mapping._id.indexed` is set to `true`.